# Adding Edit Facility to DataGridView in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

I've populated a DataGridView using a DataSet. Now I've to add edit functionality to this DataGrid. But changing data in SQL server in every value changed event will be of much overhead. So after changing the cells in intended rows, the user will press a submit button and the data only in the changed cells will be submitted to the SQL server.

Can you give a full example on this. Or some kind of good link on this. I've searched a lot. But couldn't find anything helpful.

Again using dataset quite a bit old fashioned. Can you give me an example to do this in LINQ.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would cache the changes. Then at regular intervals, or when you cached so many changes, on when the form that holds the grid closes (On/Closing event), I would commit the changes. Or how about you let the users update as many cells they want. Then you have a single submit button somewhere on that form, and when the user presses it, you commit to the database and close the form or whatever.

Regarding linq, is fairly similar to create a linq query that emulates any SQL statement used to populate the DataSet. Or consider using LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework, depending on your project.